# How to set application first open date in same system using java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

I want to create a small application for that purpose I want to know how to set a date in jLabel which was open the application first time in that system using java netbeans.

Comment: `Date creationDate = new Date();` at the start of the app?

Comment: And it must be not be changed and need to show every time when application run.

Comment: Using the SimpleDateformat class format date-> Store it in text file-> then read it from file to set in JLable whenever required.

Comment: Can u give me example code for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out in your main method. Read the starting date from a property file.

```
package com.java.demo;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new Date().toString());
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Comment: actually you coding is working for current date and time. when I change the date is also change. I want fixed date.

Comment: for example if I run that application it must show today's date as default and every time I run that application it must show today's date as fixed with a message "you have run this application from this date : "

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility (independent of the programming language or the IDE you use).

The reason is that you'd need administrator rights to store that information at a place where all users of the system have assess to **and** which is not likely to be deleted by accident.

You would need an *installer* to store that information at such place.

---

But If you have that you could read that file containing that information. the basic technique to do so is a `FileReader` or the `Scanner` class from the Java standard lib, but if your "system config" gets more complex you might change to some mapping framework.

Comment: I saw there is some codes which is working in android application coding .

Comment: *"I saw there is some codes which is working in android application coding"* If you have working code, what is your question all about?

Comment: In android it is using sharedpreferences  using for these type of coding. So I think there may be like any codes in Java netbeans.